# Touchpad issue keys on 2 in 1 Dell Inspiron 13 5378 don't work on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad, dell

I have 2 in 1 Dell Inspiron 13 5378. In the touchpad mode, the <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and <kbd>DELETE</kbd> buttons just don't respond.

On Windows everything is working, on Ubuntu all the touch is working except those 3 buttons.

I tried turning around the screen and changing the button positions but nothing helps.

I talked with a Dell Representative and he was like "say what?!"

Ubuntu is installed as a partition on a Windows machine. I can try reinstalling it all, but this will be the last resort.

Any insights would be amazing <3

[image: here's an image of my screen]

As suggested on [this Ubuntu Forum thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2396712) I got Onboard. It doesn't fix my problem, but it's a different keyboard, more functionalities, will do until I fix the issue properly.

Comment: I've never had a touchscreen computer myself, but seeing as the only thing that doesn't work is a few buttons in your on-screen keyboard, maybe you could try switching to a different onscreen keyboard. See here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2396712 ...there are also a few other suggestions in this post that could possibly help you

Comment: thank you my friend, got onboard, not the best alternative, but meanwhile at least
maybe next version 19.04 they'll fully support touch

Answer (score 0):

16.04 LTS is the version certified for this laptop. Newer versions dont work in my experience.